# finding identity element confusion

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It is given a binary operation such that $$x*y=2x+2y+xy+2$$ I want to find its identity element if there exists.

I know that if there exists an identity element, it must be unique. Moreover, I know that $e*e=e$. Then, $$e*e=2e+2e*e^2+2=e$$ $$e^2 +3e +2=0 \rightarrow e=-2 \lor e=-1$$

Then, there is not any identity element, because we should have had only one identity.

However, the solution says that $x*e=x$ for all x values(because of this operation is commutative, $e*x=x$)

Then, $$x=2x+2e+xe+2$$

If we take $x=0$, then $e=-1$.

I am confused here. Who is right me or the book ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde it is just the given, i think it must be on real numbers. book doesnt say anything much more about the binary operation

Comment: @DietrichBurde i cant see any mistake $e*e=e=e^2 +4e+2$,then $e^2 +3e+2=0$

Comment: Down vote, WHY ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde How is the book right ? book says that the identity is $-1$ ,but you say that $e=-1,-2$ make no sense. you contradict yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $t*t=t$ for some binary operation $*$, then $x$ is [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) of that operation. As you've already worked out, for operation $x*y=2\cdot x+2\cdot y +x\cdot y +2$, being idempotent is equivalent to satisfy $t^2+3\cdot t+2=0$. This means *only* that:

1. unique idempotents for $*$ are:  $(-1)*(-1)=-1$ and $(-2)*(-2)=-2$
2. if $*$ has neutral element *at all* it is either $-1$ or $-2$.

All that is left is to check if for arbitrary $x\in\mathbb{R}$:  $(-1)*x=x$ or $(-2)*x=x$. Note, that both cannot hold, assumed that $*$ is associative (probably another exercise). Indeed, $(-1)*x=x$ for all $x$, so $-1$ is unique neutral element of $*$.

Comment: thanks a lot :)

Comment: then the above operation is not a group in real numbers,right ? because there are two idemponents

Comment: Yes. Only idempotent in group is neutral element.